# XSLT - Best way to split and render comma separated text as HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some data in an XML element that looks like this:

```
<item value="category1,category2">Item Name</item>
```

The bit I'm interested in is the *value* attribute. I'm able to get the data contained in this attribute into a template which looks like this:

```
<xsl:template name="RenderValues">
    <xsl:param name="ValueList" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$ValueList" /> <!-- outputs category1,category2-->
</xsl:template>
```

What I want to do is to process the comma separated values in an efficient manner. What is the best way to render something like the following from inside the RenderValues template?

```
<a href="x.asp?item=category1">category1</a>
<a href="x.asp?item=category2">category2</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/)/[XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) use [the standard XPath 2.0 function tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)**.

**In [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)** one needs either to write a recursively called template or, more conveniently, use the [**`str-split-to-words`**](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/strSplit-to-Words.xsl?revision=1.2&view=markup) function/template of [**the FXSL library**](http://fxsl.sf.net).

**Here is an example of the latter**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"

>
<!--                                                 -->
   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>
<!--                                                 -->
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<!--                                                 -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:variable name="vwordNodes">
        <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
          <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="string(@value)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters" 
                          select="', &#10;'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
<!--                                                 -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vwordNodes)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
<!--                                                 -->
    <xsl:template match="word" priority="10">
      <a href="x.asp?item={.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
    </xsl:template>
<!--                                                 -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<item value="category1,category2">Item Name</item>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<a href="x.asp?item=category1" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">category1</a>
<a href="x.asp?item=category2" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">category2</a>
```

The `pDelimiters` parameter of this template allow multiple delimiting characters to be specified. In the above example, any separating character can be either a comma, a space or a new line character.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, this has been very handy. Is it possible to split text multiple times in a template using this FXSL library. I need to split texts in two parts of my XML. However, the `word` template is already used in the first one and using again will return the same fixed text in the second one. Thanks

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: Almost everything is possible. Please, ask a SO question and letm me know.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the [tokenize function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/common">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="sampleString">XML,XSLT,XPath,SVG,XPointer</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($sampleString,',')">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="str:concat('x.asp?item=', .)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/05/07/tr.html

Comment: Hi codar, great answer. I took the liberty of adding a link to the offical tokenize function definition and adapting the example in the question. As far as editing goes, this is quite a serious modification, so if you mind, please just revert. I wrote nearly exactly the same text, but you beat me

Answer (score 2):

It's a legitimate question, and the answers provided are good ones.  But if you're using XSLT 1.0, and you can't use extension functions, it's simply not possible.  XSLT templates produce result tree fragments, and XSLT can only work on node sets.  Tokenizing in XSLT requires recursion, which means calling a template, which means producing a data structure that you can't process.

If this limitation applies to you - and really, even if it doesn't - you should, if possible, solve this problem by finding the person who's generating XML whose content has to be parsed *again* after the DOM has *already parsed it* and make him or her stop.  Putting multiple values in an attribute is just plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The XML is generated by SharePoint. Specifically it's data that exists in the blog template if you enable multiple category selections for a ports. I can't use EXSLT solutions unless I can control the executions of the .NET code, which is not possible in this case.

Comment: It is possible by evaluating every character, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418884/complex-xslt-split